# Generar números aleatorios flotantes en un rango de (-100.0 a 100.0) en C

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en C que me devuelva un número flotante aleatorio entre -100.0 a 100.0

---

Mi código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){
  srand( time( NULL ) );
  int numeroAleatorio = 0;

  for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    numeroAleatorio = -100 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (100 + 100 + 1) + 1);
    // Random: NumeroMinimo + funcion rannd() / (numeroMaximo / (NumeroMaximo - (NumeroMinimo) + 1) + 1);
    printf( "%.2f\n", (float) numeroAleatorio/1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Terminal:

```
-26.00
72.00
-5.00
15.00
-33.00
54.00
-77.00
-66.00
-79.00
-15.00
```

---

**Mi problema principalmente radica en que no sé como convertir la función `rand()` o el retorno de ella en un número flotante.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente haz una conversión explícita. Así:

```
float floatAleatorio = (float)rand();
```

O también puedes usar conversión implícita multiplicando un entero por un float. Por ejemplo:

```
float numeroAleaturio = rand() * 1.0f;
```

En tu código quedaría así:

```
numeroAleatorio = -minimo + (float) rand() / RAND_MAX * (maximo - minimo + 1);
```

Comment: Y como obtendria por ejemplo 27.31?

Comment: @Japv Ya pude solucionar mi duda. Tienes la conclusión en mi respuesta.

Para generar un número como `27.31`, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

`float numeroAleatorio = 0.00, imprimirAleatorio;`

`numeroAleatorio = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;`
`imprimirAleatorio = numeroAleatorio * 28;`


Eso genera números aleatorios flotantes entre 0 y 28. Por ejemplo: `27.31`

Comment: @Japv respondí lo que el necesita. No hice el programa completo. Lee el último párrafo.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta, por el contexto que da al principio, tenía que ver con el hecho de que el número generado pudiera contener decimales. Es verdad que hacer un cast a `float` era necesario para resolver el problema, pero el cast no es la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Con la [ayuda de @Mateo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/501926) e investigación en la documentación de Microsoft, pude resolver mis dudas.

---

Código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(){
  srand( time( NULL ) );
  float numeroAleatorio = 0.00, imprimirAleatorio;

  for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    numeroAleatorio = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    imprimirAleatorio = -100 + numeroAleatorio * ( 100 + 100);
    printf("%.2f\n", imprimirAleatorio);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Terminal:

```
-99.82
48.03
-98.33
43.24
28.88
-12.62
26.47
82.87
-59.75
-54.30
```

---

Esta es la sintaxis que hay que seguir para un número flotante aleatorio con rango:

`float numeroAleatorio = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;`

Declaramos una variable de tipo float y la inicializamos con la función `rand()` siendo dividida por el casteo en flotante del número constante `RAND_MAX`

Después, asignamos el rango de números a generar

`float imprimirAleatorio = -100 + numeroAleatorio * ( 100 + 100);`

Rango:

`numeroMinimo + numeroAleatorio + (numeroMaximo - (numeroMinimo))`